# Docker breaks when trying to use created aws context

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create an AWS context for use with docker for AWS. Using the docker documentation I have successfully created a context with `docker context create ecs myecscontext` but every single time when I try to use this created context with `docker context use myecscontext` docker breaks and simply typing `docker` into the command line brings up the message `context requires credentials to be passed as environment variables` .

I already have aws envriomnent variables set and I selected `AWS environment variables` when creating the context.

Is this a bug with docker? I can only get docker to work again after this by resetting my docker engine from the docker dashboard. I am on MacOS Big Sur.

This is the documentation I am following: [Deploying Docker containers on ECS](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration)

Answer (score 11):

You can switch back to the default context by running:

```
> docker --context default context use default
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks!